# Dual display in Ubuntu

Tags: multiple-monitors

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I am running it on a Compaq Presario CQ42-291tx. I have an additional monitor from my previous desktop PC. Problem arise when i have to work and my friends wants to watch movies. I know that I can connect my monitor with my laptop. I saw it in windows, and it works here fine.

Is it possible to assign a player to play movie file on an external desktop monitor while I am working with another application on my laptop monitor?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple monitors are usually handled by the vendor proprietary drivers.  After you install those (check "additional drivers" under Dash or system/administration), you should have a vendor supplied control program.  Run this, and ensure that "clone" is unchecked, so you get two distinct desktops, select how the desktops are connected (right/left etc.) by moving the little screen images around.  By running the movie on one desktop for the external monitor, you can then use the other desktop for your work.